# Bcp stored procedure not writing file to disk

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, bcp

Below when I executing the stored procedure in either code or in sql server management studio 2008 it saids it copied successfully rows, But I am not for sure why its not writing the file to disk. can some please help me, I have been struggling with this for the pass few days. I have enable command shell and everything. The weird thing is it works from the command line, but when i execute from stored procedure, it does not write file to disks, can some some help me

```
USE [ColorDb]
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_WriteTableToTextDelimitedFile]
(
  @FilePath VarChar(256)

)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @sql varchar(8000)

SET @sql = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM ColorDb.dbo.ColorTable" queryout "'+ @FilePath +'" -c -t; -T -SXXXXXXXXXXXX'

Print @sql

exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql

END

RETURN
```

Answer (score 1):

I would print out the contents of @sql, and @FilePath.

I just ran some code through the MS SQL Server Manager Debugger window, you could step through the code. I did notice that you don't seem to have your quotes matched, and I don't see where you intialize @FilePath to anything. Looking at your last segment it looks like it has an unmatched double quote.

I didn't use any double quotes, I ran from a query in the query builder under MSSQL Server Manager. I got file output, moved files, concatenated files and what not from the query window.

Like this simple concatenation command:

```
Exec master..xp_cmdshell 'type c:\bcp\sysobjects.txt >> c:\bcp\a.txt'
```

Also this creation/output command:

```
SELECT @sql = 'bcp master..sysobjects out c:\bcp\sysobjects.txt -c -t\t -T -S' + @@servername

REPLACE( @sql, 'sysobjects.txt', @EmpRecordsFILENAME)

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

The files got created, and concatenated with these simple commands!